# Using Apply Functions In Place of For Loop In R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am pushing ahead in R and have used lapply for the first time successfully in loading files in a function called ImportData().  The working function is:

```
AllData <- lapply(files, function(i){
    read.csv(i, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })
```

AllData is list containing 4 data frames.  In the future, it will contain more.

There are two more for loops in the function that I'd like to replace with lapply.  The first is a loop that combines the Date and Time Columns into one timestamp.  The i is throwing me off in creating the apply function.

```
  for (i in 1:length(AllData))
   {
    AllData[[i]]$Date <- strptime(paste(AllData[[i]]$Date, AllData[[i]]$Time), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
    AllData[[i]] <- AllData[[i]][-2]
    }
```

The last loop is this. names(AllData) is a character vector of length 4.

```
  for (i in 1:length(names(AllData)))
  {
    cat("Time Frame: ", names(AllData)[i], "\n")
    trade(AllData[[i]])
  }
```

What is throwing me in this case is [[i]].  I cannot seem to get that to work in lapply.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

It is good to use replace `for` by one of the xxpply function, but better is to use vectorized functions.

Here for example , there is no need to used a `for` since operations are vectorized. So the first loop should be written:

```
AllData$Date <- 
         strptime(paste(AllData$Date, AllData$Time), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Same thing for the second loop:

```
cat(paste("Time Frame: ", names(AllData), "\n"))
```

**EDIT** In case you have a list of data.frames , you can use loop here:

```
  for (x in seq_along(AllData)){
       x$Date = strptime(paste(x$Date, x$Time), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  This will work if AllData was a single data frame.  However, it is a list of 4 separate data frames, so there is no AllData$Date.

Comment: @user2926358 Ah sorry. I edit my answer. Just put all this in a `lapply`. But I see that the other answer is exactly that using my vectorized solution.

Comment: @agstudy If you have a solution where you just put a vectorized solution into `lapply` I would love to see it.  I found all my other `lapply` solutions to this problem (outside of using `transform`) to be so coding inefficient that they were no better than the loop from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

For your first loop, using `lapply` in conjunction with `transform` is useful along with an anonymous function.  In this case, the `x` in the anonymous function refers to an element of the list (e.g., AllData[[1]]) which you can then use in `transform`.  I found `transform` useful here because I can ask for variables of the list element by name.

```
AllData2 = lapply(AllData, function(x) transform(x, Date = strptime(paste(Date, Time), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"), 
                              Time = NULL))
```

I don't know where the `trade` function is from, so I was uncertain what you wanted to do with the second loop.  If you clarify I may be able to give you an idea.

Comment: This was very helpful and did the trick, thank you.  The trade function is one that I wrote that reads the data, performs some calculations and prints the results, it doesn't change the data at all.